# Does nitrous.io support the endpoint library?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, nitrousio

Developing a python project on the platform and attempting [appengine endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api).

`import endpoints` throws `google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "endpoints" is not supported`.  The full stack trace is below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 695, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 688, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 525, in start
    options.yaml_files)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 556, in __init__
    server_configuration = ServerConfiguration(yaml_path)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._yaml_path)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 272, in _parse_configuration
    return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 1715, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/home/action/.google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: the library "endpoints" is not supported
  in "./app.yaml", line 21, column 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Start with a non-python project.
2. Download appengine for Linux python:

   `curl -O http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.8.9.zip`
3. Unzip and export directory in `~/.bash_profile`:

   `export PATH="$HOME/google_appengine:$PATH"`
4. Build endpoint python app [as described](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api) and run `dev_appserver.py`.
5. You can't view the Google APIs Explorer when launched from Nitrous.io, unless you [port forward](http://help.nitrous.io/nitrous-desktop/), but you can still use as a developing endpoint.

Comment: THIS IS NO LONGER TRUE AS NITROUS.IO UPDATED THEIR PYTHON/APPENGINE VERSION.  I am keeping this here in case any one wants to know how to install environments outside of the autoparts functionality.